# Is using staging table and live table considered an anti-pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

a system I am working on has a number of screens where the User saves data as they move through the system.

When they save the data gets saved to a StagingTable.  When they get to the end of the user journey and Submit the Application they have filled in the Data gets copied to a Live version of the tables.  There is also corresponding Audit Tables for the Live and Staging Tables

An example of a staging table for Car would be:

```
CarId
Manufacturer
Model
Colour
UserId
DateModified
DateCreated
```

The corresponding live table for Car would be:

```
CarId
Manufacturer
Model
Colour
UserId
DateModified
DateCreated
StagingCarId
```

To me this seems like a bad design in that nearly every piece of data in the DB is duplicated.  My suggestion to an Architect would be to add a bool IsSubmitted to the table and then set it to true on submitting.

The User can submit the application multiple times - and the architect was making the point what if the User Submitted the data - in my case that would check the IsSubmitted to true.  If they then went back into the Application and did a delete and saved - that would delete the row from the table - but if they did not Submit (a valid scenario) - it would mean the actual submitted data would be wrong - it would be one row less than what they actually submitted

Just wondering is there a better approach to this scenario than using Staging and Live tables which are a mirror of each other for the most part

Comment: Your design sounds good to me. Why can't the data just be stored in the user's browser local storage or something?

Comment: I think a lot depends on the requirements we do not know about - What analysis of un-submitted data is made - is any trend analysis on un-submitted data made to understand why the user failed to submit? What purging of un-submitted data is there - if its frequent enough, its not really doubling storage.

Comment: Yeah this is one approach. Another approach would be to add a status column. Then when the user finishes you simply change the status. This of course requires that all your other queries take into account this status. But is eliminates all the duplicate data. This question is very likely to get closed as being primarily opinion based.

Comment: @SeanLange - yeah I guess I was looking for other approaches to the scenario so cheers for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question, as stated, is no.  You cannot reasonably object to this as an anti-pattern *per se*.

This is a modeling question that cannot be answered as a matter of "best practices".  For instance a "Loan Application" is something different-enough from a "Loan" that it *should* be in a separate table.  It depends on what you are modeling, and how your developers and users think about the domain.